# What is the default style Set in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, microsoft-office-2016

When you look in `Design tab` in `Style Sets`; how can you find out what is the default style set. When you fresh install Office and there are no customizations at all. I'm unable to find the name of it.

Answer (score 0):

Hover over the style. The first one (left side) is "This Document's Style Set" which is the Normal Style (and the Default Style).

The next one is "Basic Elegant". The third one from the left is "Basic Simple" and so on.

These are subset of the "Document's Style set and do not change a style.

True Styles as a Pull Down in the Home Ribbon.